# Script is not executing from external file

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask

I've been stuck with a very stupid and mysterious issue for a few hours. JQuery works when between `<script></script>`, but not when called from an external file. I must be making a stupid mistake, but where??

I have this in my HTML (standard bootstrap imports, as you'll notice):

```
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/js/docs.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
<!-- Custom JavaScript
    ================================================== -->

<div class="col-xs-4">
    <div id="my_camera"></div>
    <div id="send-button"></div>

</div>
...
```

now, if I code directly inside the file, as below, `Title` gets displayed as expected:

```
<!-- Custom JavaScript
        ================================================== -->
    <script>$(function() {
    $( "#Title" ).append( '<h1 class="text-capitalize">Title</h1>' );
});
    </script>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div id="my_camera"></div>
        <div id="Title"></div>

    </div>
```

However if I put the **same** code in `custom.js`, nothing is displayed. Here is `custom.js` content:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#Title" ).append( '<h1 class="text-capitalize">Title</h1>' );
});
```

And the modified HTML:

```
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
        ================================================== -->
        <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../../assets/js/docs.min.js"></script>
        <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
        <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
    <!-- Custom JavaScript
        ================================================== -->
    <script src="custom.js"></script>   

    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div id="my_camera"></div>
        <div id="Title"></div>

    </div>
```

Comment: The only thing that can be wrong here is that your path is wrong. We can't help with that give the information we have.

Comment: Try wrapping your code in `$(document).ready(function () {});`

Comment: @Mikey, that's what `$(function() {...` does.

Comment: @isherwood I suspect so. But  the 2 files are in the same directory!!

Comment: Well, that's a simple thing to check in the console. Look for 404 errors.

Comment: @isherwood I don't know but a self invoking function does not necessarily wait for the DOM to be ready. But I could be wrong on this one

Comment: @Mikey yes, you are wrong. Check [docs](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

Comment: @Regent Thanks never knew it was a shorthand

Comment: The code runs before the HTML is rendered in both cases. Document.ready isn't a factor regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems in fact to not have anything to do with Jquery. I am using the Flask python framework, and it seems I cannot set paths to directories other than `static`. So anything outside from `static` is not seen by the app.

```
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../assets/js/docs.min.js"></script>
<!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
<script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
<!-- Custom JavaScript
================================================== -->
<script src="../static/js/custom.js"></script>
```

custom.js content:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $( "#left-col" ).append( '<h1 class="text-capitalize">Title</h1>' );
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps your JS is getting called before the HTML is rendered. Try wrapping it in the ready function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#Title" ).append( '<h1 class="text-capitalize">Title</h1>' );
});
```

Comment: `$(function() { ... });` is shorthand for document.ready in jQuery. Also, the scenario would exist in both cases.

Comment: Once again verify the exact path of your custom.js file, else post the exact error you are getting in console.

Comment: @Saurabh why do you post your comment under answer, not under question?

Comment: @Regent by mistake posted.